# Cómo acceder a un valor de un objeto que tiene la propiedad con un nombre con guion medio (-) en js

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de acceder al siguiente objeto. El mismo lo obtengo desde una API. Pero es más o menos así:

```
const appearance = {
"eye-color": "Yellow",
"gender": "Male",
"hair-color": "No Hair",
"height": (2) ["6'8", "203 cm"]
}
```

Lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
 appearance.eye-color
```

el problema es que salta un error en pantalla que dice: `color no ha sido definido.` Me pasa lo mismo con `hair-color`, no así con los demás.

Alguien sabe como acceder a esos valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const appearance = {
    "eye-color": "Yellow",
    "gender": "Male",
    "hair-color": "No Hair",
    "height": (2) ["6'8", "203 cm"]
}

console.log(appearance["eye-color"])
```

Así puedes hacerlo

Comment: Si es verdad, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Que bueno que te sirva, pero dicen que mejor que un comentario dando gracias es valorar la respuesta con votos.

Comment: Como te comento el compañero, si la respuesta te fue de utilidad, por favor aceptala como valida.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo no utilizar ese tipo de nomenclatura, usa en cambio camelCase, sin comillas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const appearance = {
    eyeColor: "Yellow",
    gender: "Male",
    hairColor: "No Hair",
    height: ["6'8", "203 cm"]
}

console.log(appearance.eyeColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que aceder al objeto en forma de array

```
const appearance = {
    "eye-color": "Yellow",
     "gender": "Male",
      "hair-color": "No Hair",
      "height": (2) ["6'8", "203 cm"]
    }

   console.log(appearance["eye-color"])
```